# Redirecting from .info to .com

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have two domain seooutlook.info,seooutlook.com both pointing to the same server.

Now since both pointing to the same server,i dont want Google to see Duplicate files at two different domain names.

Till now i managed to redirect seooutlook.info to seooutlook.com

using htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seooutlook\.info$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.seooutlook\.info$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.seooutlook\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

but this fails at situation like this

```
Example: www.seooutlook.info/site/google.com
```

it didn't redirect domain to seooutlook.com.

what i want here is to redirect

```
  www.seooutlook.info/site/google.com
```

to

```
 www.seooutlook.com/site/google.com
```

There are lots of files like google.com in my server..so what i need here is a universal redirection rule.

and one more thing iam not good at ht-access rules so plz help me with this ..

Thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} seooutlook.info$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.seooutlook.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this work ..thanks thought i have to tweak it a little bit in my case  @lucas willwms